# Concurrent editing merging

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to implement simple concurrent editing model. Adding and removing data to file is handled by events. 
Process of an event:

1. Ask for change ID(basically a timestamp)
2. Get ID from server
3. Send change to server with the ID.(change consists of index, event type(ADD,REMOVE), optional char(for ADD))
4. Server gets change
5. Event queue is first come first serve(Multiple changes can have same original string), so i apply event to content
6. New content should be next event base, so next events index needs to be moved(merge).

Problem is how do I merge the new content with base(multiple events can have same base).

Server has string: `"Hello Worl"`

2 client want to change, both get this as the base.
C1 adds "," to index 5(start counting from 0)
C2 adds "d" to index 10.

Because "," was added then "d" would result in `"Hello, Wordl"`.
Index should be moved +1(in this case).

General case we can have more event simultaneously, so the merging will be more complex. the differences could be +10 or -5 etc.

What would be a good way to detect how many changes were made to content before index X in the base?

I am using python.

EDIT:

I thought about it and i think i know what would be a good way to solve it.
Lets say we have strings abcdefg and abdeg. I would now like to extend the second string so that it would match the first one in length: abcdefg - ab#de#g. From this i could see where the changes are. I dont care about substitutions only inserts and removes. This thing would work on most case but will have problem whit strings like aaaaaa and aa, but these kind of strings are unlikely in my system. Anyone know what should i use to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what your solution is. Can you post (pseudo) code of what you mean, and action for all clients in your example

Comment: I cant think of a pseudocode that would achieve this. The idea is to compare 2 strings(old, new), find all the diffrences. Because index isbased on the old string, we need to know all the changes,from old to new, that happen before the index, so that we could modify index accordingly.

Comment: See my answer, perhaps a String primitive is not the way to go.

Comment: Linked list is not possible, because python does not have it. We had a though about operational transformation, but we dont have enough time to implement it. The implementations does not have to be clean it just hast to work for most of the cases. And knowing the inde movement is also neede, because on the text editor side we need to sync it with server.

Comment: The point is conceptual. You can't insert/remove around characters using indices for exactly the problems you encountered. Implementation can be done in many ways. A linked list fake is easy enough to create in Python thought it's not natural(A node with 2 references and a data field). Another option I thought of is saving the reference string ID, so the original is 0, after an update it's 1 and so forth. The server saves all versions until cleanup to incorporate all updates and get rid of all the versions. This is more akin to a tree.

Comment: Refrence ID idea we had also. thatway we could do something like
("abcd",[0,0,0,0]), now we insert e to index 1 and we get ("aebcd",[0,1,1,1]). We can use this ID list for the next element if it has the same base "abcd". Issue arises when we have 3 clients. C1 requests, C2 rewquests, C1 is filled, C3 requets, C2 is filled. Now the question is what do we do with C3. C1 and C2 filling is easy because of the same base of change. But C3 has a base where C1 is applied. If we add the 0 for new element in to the vector. we get a problem with C1 and C2. History wouldnt help mutch here.